# Statement list composition

Tags: metaprogramming, nim-lang

I need to split a statement list into multiple parts, like this:

```
import macros

macro test: stmt =
    var first = quote do:
        var x = 1
    var second = quote do:
        echo x
    result = newStmtList()
    first.copyChildrenTo(result)
    second.copyChildrenTo(result)

    echo result.repr

test
```

But the compiler tells me this:

```
[..]

  var x = 1
  echo x
minimalist.nim(14, 0) Info: instantiation from here
minimalist.nim(7, 13) Error: undeclared identifier: 'x'
          echo x
```

This is very confusing given that `x` is declared in the node list. How do I make this work properly? (in case it's not obvious, I do need the AST to be split into multiple parts for other reasons)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Nim will enforce the macro hygiene rules for the code inside quoted blocks. This means that symbol names, introduced in one block, won't be visible in another. You can get around this by introducing a variable for the shared symbol like this:

```
import macros

macro test: stmt =
  var x = genSym()

  var first = quote do:
      var `x` = 1

  var second = quote do:
      echo `x`

  result = newStmtList()
  first.copyChildrenTo(result)
  second.copyChildrenTo(result)

test
```

Under the hood, quote is powered by the `getAst` operation applied to a non-dirty template. If you use the lower-level mechanism yourself, it's also possible to disable the hygienic behavior of the quoted templates like this:

```
import macros

macro test: stmt =
  template first {.dirty.} =
    var x = 1

  template second {.dirty.} =
    echo x

  result = newStmtList()
  getAst(first()).copyChildrenTo(result)
  getAst(second()).copyChildrenTo(result)

test
```

This will get the same results. Keep in mind that `quote` will eventually gain a flag that controls the dirty-ness of the quoted code.

Answer (score 2):

If you compare the ASTs you can see what's going wrong:

```
dumpTree:
  var x = 1
  echo x
```

This prints:

```
StmtList
  VarSection
    IdentDefs
      Ident !"x"
      Empty
      IntLit 1
  Command
    Ident !"echo"
    Ident !"x"
```

Then in your example:

```
macro test: stmt =
    var first = quote do:
        var x = 1
    var second = quote do:
        echo x

    result = newStmtList()
    first.copyChildrenTo(result)
    second.copyChildrenTo(result)

    echo result.treeRepr

test
```

This prints:

```
StmtList
  VarSection
    IdentDefs
      Sym "x"
      Empty
      IntLit 1
  Command
    Sym "echo"
    Ident !"x"
```

Notice the difference? Once "x" is an Ident, the other time a Sym. The symbols should not have been looked up for, maybe this should be changed in the compiler. But for now you can help out yourself and replace all Syms with Idents again to force a new lookup:

```
import macros

proc symsToIdents(n): PNimrodNode {.compiletime.} =
    if n.kind == nnkSym:
        return newIdentNode($n)

    result = n
    for i in 0 .. <result.len:
      result[i] = symsToIdents(n[i])

macro test: stmt =
    var first = quote do:
        var x = 1
    var second = quote do:
        echo x

    result = newStmtList()
    first.copyChildrenTo(result)
    second.copyChildrenTo(result)
    result = symsToIdents(result)

test
```

Edit: Reported as a possible bug now: https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues/1843

Comment: this is exactly what I needed to make my code work, though I feel like this is a compiler/standard library bug